# String separation in unix shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh, cut

```
STRINGS=str1,str2,str3
```

I want each string seperated by space as given below:

```
STRING1=`echo $STRINGS | cut -d',' -f1` ==> gives "str1"

REMAINING_STRING=`echo $STRINGS | cut -d',' -f2- | 
    sed -e 's/,/ /g'` ==> gives "str2 str3"
```

But when the string contains only one entry, for e.g STRINGS=str1 , then REMAINING_STRING is also populating with same value as STRING1. I want REMAINING_STRING to be null when the STRINGS contain only one entry.

```
STRINGS=str1

STRING1=`echo $STRINGS| cut -d',' -f1` ==> gives "str1"

REMAINING_STRING=`echo $STRINGS | cut -d',' -f2- | sed -e 's/,/ /g'`
```

==> gives "str1", But this should come as null.

How to do this in unix shell?

Comment: It works for me. What OS version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ STRINGS=str1
$ echo $STRINGS | cut -d',' -f2- | sed -e 's/,/ /g'
str1
$ echo $STRINGS | cut -s -d',' -f2- | sed -e 's/,/ /g'
$
```

Explanation of `-s` from the man page.

```
   -s, --only-delimited
          do not print lines not containing delimiters
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-a` flag of the read command, to split the string into an array. Example:

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

strings=str1,str2,str3
IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "$strings"
echo "First element: ${arr[0]}"
echo "Second element: ${arr[1]}"

strings=str1
IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "$strings"
echo "First element: ${arr[0]}"
echo "Second element: ${arr[1]}"

$ ./script.sh 
First element: str1
Second element: str2
First element: str1
Second element:
```

The alternative method of splitting the string with

```
IFS=, arr=($strings)
```

will also work for most strings, but will fail in there is pathname expansion, E.g. `arr=(*)` would match all files in the current directory (as konsolebox noted).

Comment: `IFS=',' arr=($strings)` may still be subject to pathname/filename expansion so better have `IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "$strings"`.

Answer (score 1):

Extension of `user000001`'s answer:

```
$ cat strings.sh
#!/bin/bash

function splitstr {
  local a
  set -f
  IFS=, a=($1); str_first=$a; unset a[0]; str_rest="${a[@]}"
  set +f
}

splitstr 'one,*,three,four'; echo -e "<$str_first>\t<$str_rest>"
splitstr 'one';              echo -e "<$str_first>\t<$str_rest>"
splitstr '';                 echo -e "<$str_first>\t<$str_rest>"


$ ./strings.sh
<one>   <* three four>
<one>   <>
<>      <>
```